# compare the digits of large amount of double values with three constants

Tags: java

i am writing i program to compute the result of a series and compute how many times the result have the same digit of three constant :

example :

```
 //the result is the value of the variable result at each iteration 
 iteration           result
 1                  3.16661
 2                  3.16621
 3                  3.16664
 4                  3.16661


  //what i want is to calculate how many times the variable result had 
   these digits: 

3.16661  ------> 1   //here it is twice
3.166    ------> 4   // all 4 has these digits
3.1666   ------> 3
```

I thought of storing it as String and compare each char but this insane

my loop is :

```
for(int i=1; i<400 ; i++) {
    result+=Math.pow(-1,i+1)*4.0/(2*i-1);
}
```

using char will lead to inefficiency and it is a sign of lack of experience 
so I am tried to guess I way to do it in an efficient way

Comment: It sounds like you haven't [searched the internet yet](/help/how-to-ask), based on the fact that you're definitely not the first person trying to do this. There are plenty of examples of common substring counting not just on the internet at large, but even right here on Stackoverflow, so please remember to put in the effort to look around (search and research", as our policy article calls it) before posting questions to SO. Remember: this is [not a general help forum](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans -- He said he thought doing it as strings was crude and wanted to know if there was a better way, presumably keeping the values as numbers.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans i have searched but i don't know what i call this so i tried searching finding nothing then i came here since i don't know what excactly this can be called.. also i tried many ways looking for the most efficient way

Comment: @JosephLarson unless there is an explanation of _why_, e.g. with code that shows things are poorly performant, someone saying they don't want to do something often has "cool, but if you haven't tried the obvious, try that first anyway" as only proper response. This is still the common substring problem, and there are many pages on the web, and answers on SO, that explain how to implement it, using a variety of datatypes (the one datatype we're _not_ dealing with here, though, is "actual numbers", because we're pattern-matching sequences)

Comment: Have you tried sorting the list, then looking at the difference between the entries? e.g. if the difference is less than 0.001 then you know the first 2 digits are the same, less than 0.0001 then the first 3 digits are the same, etc.

Comment: @MhdGhd search for finding a "common substring". That should get you on your way just fine. (a "string" in this case is _not_ the string datatype, but a sequence of anythings, like digits, letters, bytes, rgb values; whatever can be programmatically expressed in a list form)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans you are saying there are many actually you said it twice so why don't you just share a link. or you haven't searched please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans this is not what i want .. i am dealing with a large set of Data